# STL map - insert or update

Tags: c++, stl

I have a map of objects and I want to update the object mapped to a key, or create a new object and insert into the map. The update is done by a different function that takes a pointer to the object (void update(MyClass *obj))

What is the best way to "insert or update" an element in a map?

Answer (score 24):

The [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Comment: This can yield elegant code, if you want to insert a default `MyClass` object, and then update it.  If you need to insert a non-default object, or not update the inserted value, Charles's solution is probably better.

Comment: `update(my_map[key])`? That would also mean that you `update` always (which is not clear from the question).

Comment: What if the key doesn't exist?

Comment: @Konrad: A default constructed element will be inserted and returned.  That might or might not be the desired semantics, it depends on how everything works.

Answer (score 13):

With something like the following snippet:

```
std::map<Key, Value>::iterator i = amap.find(key);

if (i == amap.end())
    amap.insert(std::make_pair(key, CreateFunction()));
else
    UpdateFunction(&(i->second));
```

If you want to measure something that might improve performance you might want to use `.lower_bound()` to find where an entry and use that as a hint to insert in the case where you need to insert a new object.

```
std::map<Key, Value>::iterator i = amap.lower_bound(key);

if (i == amap.end() || i->first != key)
    amap.insert(i, std::make_pair(key, CreateFunction()));
                                       // Might need to check and decrement i.
                                       // Only guaranteed to be amortized constant
                                       // time if insertion is immediately after
                                       // the hint position.
else
    UpdateFunction(&(i->second));
```

Comment: I think you effectively need to decrement `i` if it's not equal to `amap.begin()`. And thus the obvious question: how to give as an hint that it should be inserted in first position ? I suppose it works with the no-hint version :/

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of a warty requirement. An implementation *could* make it efficient if the hint was immediately after the insertion position. This would seem to be neater... and this is how it's been fixed: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#233

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
map<int,MyClass*> mymap;
map<int,MyClass*>::iterator it;

MyClass* dummy = new MyClass();
mymap.insert(pair<int,MyClass*>(2,dummy));

it = mymap.find(2);
update(it.second);
```

here a nice reference [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

Comment: If you're going to go that route: `MyClass& obj = mymap[2]; update(&obj);`

Comment: Yes but with [] you should know that if the object doesn't exist, it creates a new one (resulting that second is a null pointer)

Comment: No.  If the key is not present, it inserts one, and then returns a reference to it.  So you're guaranteed to get a valid object so long as there's memory for it.  Even if that weren't the behavior, it certainly wouldn't yield an invalid reference.  An exception is much more likely in that case.

Comment: @Dennis Yes it will create a new pair, but the value (it.second) is a pointer to a MyClass object that hasn't been set.

Comment: OOh, you're using dynamic objects.  Yes, that does make a difference.  You shouldn't do that, though.  Its fraught with problems.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator[]` already does, what you want. See [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/) for details.

Comment: oddly enough, the reference is wrong. The reference says that operator [] is equivalent to insert, but m.insert(std::make_pair("a", "1")); m.insert(std::make_pair("a", "2")); doesn't update m. m["a"] stays "1" . m["a"] = "2" would update m.  Where: map<string, string> m;

Answer (score 0):

The return value of insert is "a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place."

Therefore you can simply do

```
auto result = values.insert({ key, CreateFunction()});
if (!result.second)
    UpdateFunction(&(result.first->second));
```

NOTE: 
Since your question involved raw pointers, and you said you wanted your Update function to take a pointer, I have made that assumption in my snippet. Assume that CreateFunction() returns a pointer and UpdateFunction() expects a pointer.

I'd strongly advise against using raw pointers though.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, function *[insert_or_assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign)*  insert if not existing and update if there.