# Memory address are the same after creating new tensor

Tags: c++, libtorch

```
std::map<std::string, torch::Tensor*> tmpFloatActivations = model.getActivations();
std::map<std::string, torch::Tensor*> floatActivations;
floatActivations.insert(tmpFloatActivations.begin(), tmpFloatActivations.end());
for (auto& mapIter : tmpFloatActivations) {
     cout << "[DEBUG-BEFORE] layerName: " << mapIter.first << " address: " << (void*)mapIter.second << endl;
     torch::Tensor* clonedTensor = new torch::Tensor(mapIter.second->clone());
     floatActivations.insert(std::make_pair(mapIter.first, clonedTensor));
     cout << "[DEBUG-AFTER] layerName: " << mapIter.first << " address: " << (void*)floatActivations[mapIter.first] << endl;
 }
```

The address of before and after are the same even if I create new tensor from clone tensor.

If I comment this line `floatActivations.insert(tmpFloatActivations.begin(), tmpFloatActivations.end());`, the address are different. Why does this happen?

Comment: [RTFM](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). You have a memory leak. *Inserts element(s) into the container, **if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key**.*

Comment: You mean, new element aren't inserted into the container if the container already has the same key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STL map - insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786649/stl-map-insert-or-update)